# How to work with ssh in PhpStorm?

Tags: php, netbeans, ssh, phpstorm

I have the project in the remote server and i have only ssh access. How i can work with this project? I am looking for information for either PhpStorm or NetBeans.

Comment: You can use [`rsync`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) to send the files live after editing them in the IDE.

Comment: Use Version Control + Deploy Server

Comment: Yeah, you shouldnt be working directly on a server anyhow. Set up  local environment to work with, then push to the server for final testing.

Comment: @prodigitalson Nobody said it is a production server. I use a remote server for development too and I find it useful.

Comment: @prodigitalson

I'm currently in a position working for a large company that does not already have an "out the box" build for local environments. This is due to cost considerations.  Here are a few.

1) software licenses for underlying software.
2) implementing and maintaining a local environment build script
3) an already working remote development environment.

Sure I'd argue that Best-Practice is to have local dev installations however, anyone that has been around a sufficiently complex enterprise application knows there is a difference between ideal and real.

Please be constructive

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have several options, depending on your system.

1. You can `rsync` or `scp` up your files when you want to publish.
2. You can use version control (`cvs`, `svn`, `git`, `mercurial`, ...) and via ssh perform an "update" when you wish your code to go live.
3. You can set up a `sshfs` filesystem locally.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about NetBeans, but PhpStorm has a feature that allows uploading files as soon as they change to a server (via FTP or SSH).

I don't have a lot of experience with this feature but it does seem to work well. PhpStorm can also be configured to deploy changes that occurred outside (it seems to do so as soon as it regains focus). It also seems to properly delete files that have been deleted from the project, so it's a real sync, not just "upload".

See how to configure it under "To have PhpStorm upload changed files automatically" here: http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/uploading-and-downloading-files.html